# Async call generates " Error: Can't wait without a "fiber", even with _wrapAsync

Tags: meteor, event-loop

I've been having a problem using an RSS parser in meteor. It's an async call, so it needs ot be wrapped, however it still doesn't seem to work. I presume this is because the anonymous on('readable' function is outside the fiber, but I can't see how to resolve it.

```
var FeedParser = Meteor.require('feedparser');
var request = Meteor.require('request');

function getBlog(url, parameter, id){

    request(parameter)
        .on('error', function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        })
        .pipe(new FeedParser())
        .on('error', function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        })

        .on('readable', function () {
            var stream = this,
                item;
            while (item = stream.read()) {
                Items.insert(new_item);                
            }
        });
    }

var wrappedGetBlog = Meteor._wrapAsync(getBlog);


Meteor.methods({
    blog: function (url, parameter, id) {
        console.log('parsing blog');
        var items = wrappedGetBlog(url, parameter, id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Meteor._wrapAsync()` expects the wrapped function to return error and result to a callback.  Your function, `getBlog()`, does not do that so _wrapAsync is not the right approach.

I have wrapped [that function](https://raw.github.com/mikowals/simple_rss/bef60e0dfde6d0d13bd0c341226ee5b5e4a89213/packages/feedparser/feedparser.js) before but used a Future.

That approach allowed me to call feedparser from a `Meteor.method()`, which doesn't allow async functions, but you are also trying to do an `insert` inside the readable event.  I think that `insert` will complain if it is not in a fiber.  Maybe like this would also be necessary:

```
var r = request( parameter );
r.on( 'response' , function(){

  var fp = r.pipe( new FeedParser() );  //need feedparser object as variable to pass to bindEnvironment 

  fp.on('readable', Meteor.bindEnvironment( 
    function () {
      var stream = this,
        item;
      while (item = stream.read()) {         
        Items.insert(new_item);                
      }
    }
    , function( error ){ console.log( error );}
    , fp // variable applied as `this` inside call of first function 
  ));
});
```

---

Fibers is another option...

```
var Fiber = Npm.require( "fibers" );

 .on('readable', function () {
    var stream = this,
        item;
    while (item = stream.read()) {         
        Fiber( function(){
          Items.insert(new_item);
          Fiber.yield();
        }).run();                
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. The trouble is that doing it this way causes the stream variable to loose it's context so that it no longer has the stream.read() method. I'm finding the syntax of Feed Parser very confusing...

Comment: Could also do with a fiber.  Passing the outputs back to the method and letting it do the insert also works.

Comment: Amazing, works perfectly. Looks like I might have to start understanding Fibers.